# Source tag not displaying image even though URL is correct

Tags: html

I'm trying to use WebP images and have PNG fallback in case the browser doesn't support WebP, and for this I am using the `<picture>` tag, however, things don't seem to be working as intended. Right now, the image which gets rendered is the PNG instead of WebP even though I'm using Google Chrome. If I'm understanding correctly, the PNG image should be the fallback in case all previous sources fail.

Both URLs are correct and point to the WebP and PNG version of the images

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="http://localhost:8080/img/01PZ047.webp">
    <img class='responsive-image' src="http://localhost:8080/img/01PZ047.png">
</picture>
```

Comment: I just tried to implement your example with `https://via.placeholder.com` examples with some broken urls (`https://ljahsjdh` etc.). It seems that whenever the url is considered "broken" in the `srcset`, it negates the fallback...? This would also be the case for `.webp` files as the urls would be unrecognisable. Wish I could upvote this more because I cannot replicate the functionality detailed in the doco. Also tried on Firefox and seems broken as well. I am thoroughly confused.....

Comment: [Can't repro](https://jsfiddle.net/7qgct06d/), there must be something else on your hand.

Comment: @Kaiido interestingly, if you jumble the URL in your srcset to something invalid, your example does not fallback to the img src ?

Comment: @Zze not sure to follow your comment. <img> inside <picture> is not meant for a network issue fallback, but for an unsupported feature falllback. They do determine which source to load before even loading any of these, based on the media and type.  That's only normal that when a source is broken, they don't fallback to anything else than `alt`.